# XML to CSV with nested elements (xsltproc)

Tags: xml, bash, xslt, csv

I'm trying to convert a XML to CSV using xsltproc.

I currently have

```
--XSL template
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/*/child::*">
<xsl:for-each select="child::*">
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>",            </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="position()  = last()">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>"  <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

--XML (they are two separate files 
    <root>
<summary>
    <field1>a</field1>
    <field2>b</field2>
    <field3>c</field3>
    <field4>d</field4>
        <data>
            <field5>e</field5>
            <field6>f</field6>
        </data>
        <user_info>
            <field7>g</field7>
            <field8>h</field8>
        </user_info>
   </summary>
 </root>
```

But how to i include nested elements from the XML? I have 3 nested elements.

Currently i am getting
"field one", "field two", "field three", "field four", "field 5,6,7,8,9,10"

I'd like to see

```
field1, field 2, field 3, field 4, field 5, field 6, field 7, field 8
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"
```

Comment: Please post an example of the source XML and the expected output.

Comment: I am afraid that's not a good example: the element names are invalid (contain spaces). It's also not clear which elements are to be included in the result. Ideally, you would know the XML structure in advance, and so you would be able to name them explicitly by name **and** by path. Otherwise you will need some selection criteria, for example: the name of the element starts with "field".

Answer (score 0):

Store all elements whose name starts with "field" in a variable. Then, iterate twice over the contents of `$fields`. The first time, output all element names, the second time the content of each element.

That way, you don't have to meddle with the nested structure. This line:

```
<xsl:if test="position() != last()">
```

makes sure no comma is inserted if the last element is being processed.

Assuming correct input (no spaces in element names), this is a possible solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="fields" select="//*[starts-with(name(),'field')]"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
     <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
     <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,&#32;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>

  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

  <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
     <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
     <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,&#32;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives you the following output:

```
field1, field2, field3, field4, field5, field6, field7, field8
"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"
```